# unable load data into hive using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive

unable to write the data into hive using pyspark through jupyter notebook .

giving me below error

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o99.saveAsTable.
>   : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;

Note these steps already tried:

1. copied the hdfs-site.xml , core-site.xml to /conf of hive
2. removed metasotore_db and created again using below cmd
   $HIVE_HOME/bin/schematool –initschema –dbtype derby

Comment: from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, HiveContext

SparkContext.setSystemProperty("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:10000")

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("example-pyspark-read-and-write").getOrCreate()
data = [('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4), ('Fifth', 5)]
df = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data)

df.show()

# Write into Hive
df.write.saveAsTable('example'

Comment: this piece of code i tried and giving me error : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate

Answer (score 0):

did you use spark-submit for running your script?
Also you should add -> ".enableHiveSupport()" like that:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("yourapp") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```